# Unusual graph using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, graph, svg

How do I make this graph using javascript?

What library can handle this (canvas/svg)?

[image]

Comment: [`Raphaël JavaScript Library`](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: I'm a newbie on this, provide please an alike designed example

Comment: You could use SVG or Canvas, depends on what browsers you need to target. Raphael uses VML as a fallback on IE, so its a good option if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: @Brain, You have failed to show any drive toward solving your own question. Did you even run a google search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HighCharts

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/areaspline